# HTML не открывает JS файл

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мой `url` `/course/{id}"`. Из за того что в `url` есть `id`, `html` страница игнорирует `<script>`. Все остальное работает нормально.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/dd-course.js"></script>
```

В других страницах, без `{id}` оно подтягивает js.

Comment: структуру каталогов скрином покажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/dd-course.js"></script>
> ```

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/dd-course.js"></script>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app/dd-course.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает(

Comment: @FediaCholak,дополнил. Но вообще-то надо по-нормальному делать.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)